# function count() is a variable in PL/Pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, plpgsql

I'm having a weird problem. In a database I installed the plpgsql language but in this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_sala() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE i integer;
DECLARE IdConfAux integer;
DECLARE count integer; 
DECLARE a integer;

BEGIN   
    LOCK TABLE "TabelaSalas" IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;

    UPDATE "TabelaSalas" SET "NumJogadoresAtual" = 0, "EstadoSala"= 0,"CronometroIniciado"=0, "TempoInicioJogo"=15
    WHERE "NumJogadoresAtual"<0;

    CREATE TEMP TABLE tempIds ON COMMIT DROP AS 
    SELECT "IdConf" FROM "ConfiguracaoSalas" WHERE "Senha" IS NULL;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count FROM tempIds;
    RAISE NOTICE 'count = % ',count;

    WHILE count > 0 LOOP
        SELECT "IdConf" INTO IdConfAux FROM tempIds LIMIT 1;

        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO i FROM "TabelaSalas"
        WHERE IdConfAux = "IdConf" 
        AND "NumJogadoresAtual" = 0 ;
        RAISE NOTICE 'i= % IDCONF = %', i,IdConfAux;
            IF i=0 THEN
                RAISE NOTICE 'entrou %',IdConfAux;
                INSERT INTO "TabelaSalas"("IdConf","DataCriacao","OrdemQuestoes","NumJogadoresAtual","TempoInicioJogo","CronometroIniciado","EstadoSala")
                SELECT  IdConfAux, NOW(),"OrdemQuestoes",0,15,0,0 FROM "TabelaSalas" LIMIT 1 ;
            END IF;
        DELETE FROM tempIds WHERE "IdConf" IN (SELECT * FROM tempIds LIMIT 1);
        i=1;
        count = count - 1;      
    END LOOP;


END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

I am having this erro. It's look like the COUNT is considered a variable for the function:

```
ERRO:  erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "("
LINE 1: SELECT  $1 () FROM tempIds
                   ^
QUERY:  SELECT  $1 () FROM tempIds
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "add_sala" near line 15.
```

What I have todo to count the rows?

Comment: `count` is a keyword. Try using `rowcount` or anything else instead.

Comment: BTW Try reading some books and/or manuals on postgres and SQL in general. The function you presented is a inefficient and logically incorrect mess.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
DECLARE count integer;
```

You declared `count` as a function variable. Change the declaration of variable to something else. Like `cnt` or `count_of_something`

Answer (score 1):

This is a collision of SQL and PL/pgSQL identifiers. Please, upgrade. Modern version uses a little smarter algorithm of placing placeholders to embedded SQL, and mainly, can raise a more verbose and readable exception when collision is identified.

In this case, you are a happy man. There was a possible a strange invisible and unwanted behave - so syntax error is better.